# How to remove a list element containing a particular link attribute from an unordered list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this `unordered list` and would like to get the data-file attribute value of a link element inside the list element of the unordered list, then delete the whole list element in which it lies if it is not in array z.

```
<ul id="hithere"class="image-list">
   <li class='image-list'>
      <div class='controls'>
         <a href='#' class='image-list' data-name='myname'><img src='stop.png' ></a>
      </div>
      <span class='name'>myname12</span
   </li>
   <li class='image-list'>
      <div class='controls'>
         <a href='#' class='image-list' data-name='myname2'><img src='stop.png' ></a>
      </div>
      <span class='name'>myname1312</span
   </li>
</ul>
```

And this is my jQuery but it deletes all the list elements

```
var z = ["myname", "yourname"];
$("li.image-list a.image-list ").filter(function () {

    if ($.inArray($(this).attr('data-name'), z) == -1) {
        $(this).parent("li.image-list").empty().remove();
    }
});
```

here is the code recieving from server:

```
var box = $('#drone');


box.f_drop({
    url: 't_file.php',

    check_data:function(i,file,response){
     z=[];z.push(response.Oname);


        $("li.image-list  ").filter( function () {
         return $.inArray($(this).find('a[data-name]').attr('data-name'), z) == -1
        }).remove();

    },


});
```

why is it that all the lists are now being removed instead of just one ie the one not in array?? Also, how can i rename the data-name attribute,to say "xyz" instead.

Comment: `_out` or `z`? Which one?

Comment: hello Blacksheep, i have just re-edited it.

Answer (score 1):

There are few problems in your script

- The array is called z not _out
- The anchor element does not have a class
- the data property is called name, not filename

Try

```
var z = ["myname", "yourname"];
$("li.image-list").filter(function () {
    return $.inArray($(this).find('a[data-name]').attr('data-name'), z) == -1
}).remove();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/m2rCc/)

Comment: Thanks Arun.It works on standalone page ,but why is it that when i am getting the array z from a server response all the list is disappearing.And this is when i would like to make that change.

Comment: Also my list is dynamically created before the changes to it are to be made.